# Amazon RDS (Mysql2::Error 110)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, puma

I've had a Rails application running in production for the past 6 months, with weekly deployments, without any issue.

Now, I've been having a recurring issue for about 3 weeks and it seems to get worst every week.
When my app boots and reaches the point where it's trying to connect to the DB, I get this error :

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on '***.amazonaws.com' (110) (Mysql2::Error)
```

AFAIK, this error tells me that I've reached MySQL's max connections limit.

From the configs, I should be able to open 296 connections. My app is set to run 7 instances with each a database connection pool of 5, so it can't really exceed 70 connections when deploying a new instance.

I've never seen the connection count go above 20 in either the AWS RDS Console or the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` command.

I don't think it has anything to do with either Rails or my application server (Puma), since I can't connect through the MySQL Command-Line Tool when the issue occurs.

Has anyone had a similar issue with MySQL on RDS or MySQL itself?

Comment: `connection`, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

The database pool isn't per application, it's per process. If it's threading/multi process  per instance it could be using more than that. Have you tried restarting mysql? It sounds like you have some hanging connections for whatever reason.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid restarting it, but I might have to. I read RDS takes a while to reboot instances so I can't do it during the day. If connections were hanging, wouldn't I see them in the process list?

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting these issues recently. Could it be related to the pending-restart change of parameter group on my RDS Instance? I sure hope not. As I understand a pending change should have no effect on the current performance.

Comment: It isn't. I've done the restarts and there's nothing pending now. Still the issue comes up intermittently.